# Browsers become unresponsive for about 5 seconds before starting any download to SSD

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssd, download, discord

This happens with downloads and uplaods on Firefox, Chrome, Discord.
My D drive is a 2TB Samsung 860 SSD on the latest firmware, 200GB are still free.
The problem is not present for other drives. This even happens for files that are only a few kb in size.

I am on Windows 10 Pro 64 bit 1903

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should try updating to Windows 10 1909. That's September 2019 release of WIN 10 which is the current stable version. Updating to the most stable version usually fixes a lot of weird issues. Also make sure your 2TB drive is initialized as GPT not MBR. Even though MBR supports up to 2TB disks, you should still use GPT.

Also is this external or internal drive? If it's external ensure you use USB 3.0 or 3.1 if available, or even better, USB-C. If it's internal try using a different SATA port or make sure you're using the 6Gbps port.

There's a small possibility the drive itself could have issues or be faulty. If the above suggestions didn't help, you should run a diagnostic on the drive. If you go to Samsung's website you can download The Magician SSD management utility to do drive diagnostics and a benchmark. Just search for "Samsung Magician Software"

Comment: Also, if you right-click on your drive in Explorer, then go to Properties, then Hardware, select the proper volume, then Properties again, then Strategies, make sure the "Enable cache for write" box is unchecked. IT speeds things up when caching big amount of data, because it stays in the RAM.